# Hyperref cross-references across split documents

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Say I have a document of type

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackeage{hyperref}

%\includeonly{Chap1}
%\includeonly{Chap2}

\begin{document}

\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}

\end{document}
```

Where `Chap1` `\ref`'s labels of `Chap2` and vice versa. Using `\includeonly`, I want to compile `Chap1` to `Chap1.pdf` and `Chap2` to `Chap2.pdf`.

Is there a way to inform hyperref about this, so a reference `Chap2.pdf` will automatically be hyperlinked so that it opens the referenced location in `Chap1.pdf` ?

Comment: The instructions for the `xr-hyper` package are the same as for the `xr` package. I'll post a quick answer to explain its functioning.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your setup correctly, you have two separate standalone documents, say, `doca.tex` and `docb.tex`, and you'd like to cross-reference an item (e.g., a chapter) from Document A in Document B.

One way to achieve this objective is to use the `xr-hyper` package, which is part of the `hyperref` bundle. The `xr-hyper` pacakge works exactly like the `xr` package. E.g., suppose `doca.tex` consists of the following code:

```
%% doca.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref,xr-hyper}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Beginning of Doc A} \label{doca:chap:1}
In the beginning, \dots
\end{document}
```

Note that both the `hyperref` and `xr-hyper` packages are loaded. Compile it twice and make sure *not* to delete the file `doca.aux` as it contains important cross-referencing information.

Suppose further that `docb.tex` contains the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{doca}
\begin{document}
\chapter{End of Doc B} 
As we argued in \autoref{doca:chap:1} of Document A, \dots
\end{document}
```

The crucial extra instruction is `\externaldocument{doca}`: it tells LaTeX to search in `doca.aux` for labels to cross-references. The directive `\autoref{doca:chap:1}` will then successfully create a cross-reference to "chapter 1" of Document A.

[image]