# Identical numbering for identical references across different documents

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, numbering, packages

I'm dealing with project documentation.

For the type of projects I'm working on, that means I have a large number of individual documents, each of which cover a particular aspect of the project. But all these documents are to be read in conjunction with each other. As such, they frequently

- **cross-reference each other**, which I know how to do thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/how-do-i-keep-cross-references-across-several-documents-accurate) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170570/hyperref-cross-references-across-split-documents)
- **reference identical external documents**, which is what this question is about.

Currently, the bibliography for any one of these documents (**document A**)  citing some external document **[external S]** will assign some reference ID to it, say, **RD2**. Another document (**document B**) citing *the same* **[external S]** will generally assign a *different* reference ID  to it, say, **RD15**.

I would like *all* documents that reference the *same* external sources use the *same* reference ID for it. So, for instance, `\citep{external S}` used in either **document A** or **document B** will always show up in their bibliographies as **RD521**, for example.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `xcite`?

Comment: @egreg no I did not, because obviously, I did not know it existed! Please make an answer out of your comment

Comment: @egreg wait, it appears to be [a dupe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/use-bibliography-numbers-and-citation-from-other-file)..

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe. No problem!

Comment: @egreg yes, thanks! Astounding what knowing the correct keywords can accomplish...also surprising it didn't show up in my searches...oh well.